# search by a word and selecting the whole row in vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
srchString = "Debit"
Set rng = Worksheets("Rulebook_Temp").Cells.find(What:=srchString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False)
```

In above code in the rng i am getting debit card as result and i also return the sap code for debit card.

How the find the sap code from the card type

[image]

Comment: `sapCode = rng.offset(,2)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks i worked fine for me